# Flavored Vegetable Cooking Oil

Tags: flavor

Can I flavor cooking oil with black pepper?  I had French fries from a restaurant that tasted like they black pepper.  Delicious.  I asked the person serving them if they used a flavored oil, but he had no clue.

Comment: It's possible that the flavour could have gotten there by other means. Perhaps they either seasoned them with fine black pepper, or much more likely, they were frying other things in the same oil that left their flavour.

Comment: Could also have been white pepper, which would have been much less visible.  Best bet is to go back and ask the chef this time around.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I make fries, I tend to leave them in water for anywhere between 120 to 160 minutes as it tends to leave them crispier.

This presents a perfect opportunity to "marinate" the fries. Oftentimes, I'll add rosemary or garlic, however I would imagine adding finely ground white pepper would have the same effect.

To fry, simply drain the fries in a colander, and lay them out on a dry (and clean) towel or paper towel for 5 minutes to allow excess water to drain. Heat lard to 330F - 340F until slightly tinged golden. Remove and let cool. Then, heat the lard up to 365F - 375F and fry the cooled fries again until golden. Remove, drain excess oil (on paper towel or dry colander), salt then serve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you absulutly can add flavor to your cooking oil. Slightly heat the oil, remove from heat and add the spice you want.

It works good with chili flakes (chinese style chili oil) and herbs like rose mary and also garlic.

Comment: yeah, but for frying ? won't that burn the flavor or render it bitter ?